# Freshdesk API to Postgresql Table Issue

Tags: python, while-loop, sqlalchemy, freshdesk

I am trying to take ticket details from an API and pipe them into a Postgres table, since the API has pagination, I have a function looping to continue grabbing tickets and updating the table with them until there are no more tickets to grab.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from time import sleep

url = 'https://<my_domain>.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets'
token = '<my_token>'
db_url = 'postgresql://<server_name>:<blah>/<database_name' # I promise the URL to the left is entered correctly on my actual script,lol.



def fetch_tickets(conn, page=1, per_page=100):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token}
    params = {'page': page, 'per_page': per_page, 'updated_since': '2022-01-01'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 429:
        print('Rate limit exceeded. Waiting 60 seconds...')
        sleep(61)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = json.loads(response.content)
        flattened_data = pd.json_normalize(data)
        flattened_data.to_sql('freshdesk_tickets', conn, if_exists='replace', index=True)
        if len(flattened_data) == per_page:
            return True
    return False

engine = create_engine(db_url)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    more_tickets_remaining = True
    tickets_page = 1
    while more_tickets_remaining:
        more_tickets_remaining = fetch_tickets(conn, page=tickets_page)
        print("Loading...")
        tickets_page += 1
    conn.commit()
```

I was expecting tens of thousands of tickets to pull in to my freshdesk_tickets table, but it is only pulling in 100. I don't understand why. It seems to be looping just fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop you are using `if_exists='replace'`, this means that every time you enter the loop it drops the table, so at each iteration you are only adding 100, the previous are dropped.

From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

> if_exists{‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’
> How to behave if the table already exists.

- fail: Raise a ValueError.
- replace: Drop the table before inserting new values.
- append: Insert new values to the existing table.

You should instead use `if_exists='append'`

```
flattened_data.to_sql('freshdesk_tickets', conn, if_exists='append', index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! That totally fixed it!

Comment: @AnnaBodily glad to have helped, can you select the answer? there is an option to mark this as accepted answer

Comment: Of course! thanks again! I posted a similar question yesterday about the contact API if you wanna take a look at it! :)

Comment: @AnnaBodily I have left a comment there, can you try that and let me know, would help debug it